# Using d3js to make a candlestick or ohlc chart

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to make an OHLC or Candlestick chart with d3js or plugins built from one of it or its forks? d3.js is a very powerful charting library built in javascript and it would be nice to customize charts built using it down further using its amazing abilities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/1074045). It does exactly what you want.

Update: The link above is currently broken, but @lakenen was so kind as to provide a fixed version [here](http://bl.ocks.org/8529857).

Comment: FYI, that example looks broken now. It's trying to get `http://mbostock.github.io/d3/d3.time.js?1.25.0`, which seems to no longer exist.

Comment: It's loading the data from url. Could you tell me how to load the data from CSV and create candlestick chart?

Comment: Use `d3.csv` to load the data.

Comment: why use d3.csv? @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Well you can use any method you like to load the data, but for CSV, D3 provides `d3.csv`.

Comment: is this still the best example out there?

Answer (score 17):

I found this one, and looks very nice.

http://phrogz.net/js/d3-playground/#StockPrice_HTML

Comment: is this still the best way to do a hloc?

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is an old question but I spent lots of time looking for a working example in 2017 and found very little.

Below is a working format for a candlestick chart using d3.js v4. The data in the code below is an array which in my case was being brought in from c# in the back.

```
    var twoHundredDayCandleStickChart = [];


    var width = 900;
    var height = 500;
    var margin = 50;

    function min(a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

    function max(a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin, margin]);

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([margin, width - margin]);

    //line for the sma
    var line1 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d["date"]); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d["sma"]); });

    function buildChart(data) {

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = new Date(d.date);
            d.high = +d.high;
            d.low = +d.low;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.sma = +d.sma;
        });

    var chart = d3.select("#divId")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    y.domain([d3.min(data.map(function (x) { return x["low"]; })), d3.max(data.map(function (x) { return x["high"]; }))])

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d["date"]; }))


    chart.selectAll("line.x")
        .data(x.ticks(10))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "x")
        //.text(String)
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", margin)
        .attr("y2", height - margin)
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc");
    chart.selectAll("line.y")
        .data(y.ticks(10))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .attr("x1", margin)
        .attr("x2", width - margin)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc");


    chart.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 450 + ")") //need to change this 450 to a variable- it is how far down the axis will go
        .attr("class", "xrule") 
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-65)"
        });

    chart.selectAll("text.yrule")
        .data(y.ticks(10))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "yrule")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", 0)
        .attr("dx", 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(String);

    chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d["date"]); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(max(d["open"], d["close"])); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return y(min(d["open"], d["close"])) - y(max(d["open"], d["close"])); })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return 0.5 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return d["open"] > d["close"] ? "red" : "green"; });

    chart.selectAll("line.stem")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "stem")
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return x(d["date"]) + 0.25 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return x(d["date"]) + 0.25 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return y(d["high"]); })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return y(d["low"]); })
        .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.open > d.close ? "red" : "green"; });

    chart.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("d", line1)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);
}
```

Comment: Just quick suggestions
you dont need a min max function, use the Math.min and math.max, you dont need to draw ticks with lines either, if I am not mistaken, tickSize or some attribute can be used to do this, also the standard practice is to usually declare width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right and then go from 0 to width on the xscale instead of adding margins here, just my 2 cents

Answer (score 7):

[techan.js](http://techanjs.org/) does what you need. As shown on their home page:

> A visual, stock charting (Candlestick, OHLC, indicators) and technical analysis library built on D3. Build interactive financial charts for modern and mobile browsers.

[image: TechanJS]

There is another working example by Andre Dumas shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d), with example code. That was last updated 2017-07-07.

[image: TechanJS_demo]

Comment: I actually tried to play around with techan and i found out if you want to customised it somehow it can be nearly impossible. for instance their MACD indicator has 12,9, 26 hardcoded. I can't find a way of setting individual color for candles cause they aren't simple "rect" etcs.

Comment: Update 2018 : Techan is dead

Comment: @PirateApp in what sense?

Comment: @Pithikos last I checked library wasnt maintained anymore